# How to add two markers on map for source and destination in Android

Tags: android, maps, markers

I'm new to android programming, what I want to do is get location from two EditText source and destination and mark them on the map below, I am able to mark one marker on the map from a  EditText on click of a button:

Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/location" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Type Your Address here"
            android:layout_weight="20"
             >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/geocodeBtn" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_weight="80"
               />
    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/position" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Latitude/Longitude..." /> 

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView  
        android:id="@+id/geoMap" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"  
        android:apiKey="0I0jOn_3OgbSahP7YkXmjc3d6fn2Rwrdepi0noQ" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

This is the class code:

```
package bijoy.happy;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

//import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchByAddressActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    GeoPoint p,qt,pt;

    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }
}//end of class


    @Override 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.geoMap);   
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   
    mapView.setClickable(true);   


    // map starting point   
    int lat = (int) (51.678383 * 1000000);   
    int lng = (int) (19.334822 * 1000000);   
    pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng); 


    mapView.getController().setZoom(8);   

    mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);  

    Button geoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.geocodeBtn);   

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this);     


    geoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

        public void onClick(View v) {   
            try {   
                EditText locale = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location);   
                String locationName = locale.getText().toString();   

                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(   
                        locationName, 5);   
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {   
                    int lat = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1e6);   
                    int lng = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1e6);   

                    TextView pozycja = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.position);   
                    pozycja.setText("lat: "  
                            + addressList.get(0).getLatitude() + " lng: "  
                            + addressList.get(0).getLongitude());   

                    p = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);   
                    mapView.getController().setZoom(18);   
                    mapView.getController().setCenter(p);   

                    //---Add a location marker---
                    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                    listOfOverlays.clear();
                    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay); 


                    mapView.invalidate();

                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }   
        }   
    });   

}


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

XML code will have 1 more EditText and a button to search. Please help.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) might be able to help you: